calendR - options to display conflicting events on the same day?
Using CalendR to plot fishing days for boats. On Tuesday 02 January two boats share a fishing date, however the day is shaded green for Marlin, and you are not able to see that Fish Tales went fishing on the same day.
Is there a way to visualise both shades/colours e.g. split the day into two halves either horizontally or vertically?
I thought maybe using a symbol that indicates more than one trip on the same day and annotate it somewhere in the plot but that will be a least preferred option.
Load packages, create events & plot calander:
## load packages
library(tidyverse)
library(calendR)
library(viridis) 
library(scales)

## events
events <- rep(NA, 366) ## 2024 is a leap year

## corresponding events
events[c(3, 22, 45, 63, 100, 140, 195, 234, 300)] <- "Big Catch" ## boat 1
events[c(2, 36, 59, 123, 167, 210, 289, 340)] <- "Fish Tales" ## boat 2
events[c(2, 25, 80, 155, 255, 297, 339)] <- "Marlin" ## boat 3
events[c(1, 89, 92, 142, 143, 239, 360, 361)] <- "Holiday" ## holidays

## holiday to come last
desired_order <- factor(c(levels = c("Big Catch", "Fish Tales", "Marlin", "Holiday"))) 

## select desired order and colourway
show_col(viridis_pal()(5)) ## colour palette = viridis
print(viridis_pal()(5)) 

## order colours
ordered_colours <- c("#3b528bff", "#21908cff", "#5dc863ff", "lightgray")[order(desired_order)]

## plot
calendR(year = 2024, start = "M",
        special.days = events,
        special.col = c(ordered_colours), 
        lty = 1, bg.col = "white",    
        subtitle.col = 1,
        weeknames = c("M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S"),
        day.size = 3.5,
        orientation = "l",
        legend.pos = "bottom"
)



Would it work to set up other keys/colors for combinations?
You could do something like this.

b2 <- c(2, 36, 59, 123, 167, 210, 289, 340)
b3 <- c(2, 25, 80, 155, 255, 297, 339)

b2_3 <- intersect(b2, b3)


boat2 <- setdiff(b2, b2_3)
boat3 <- setdiff(b3, b2_3)

events[boat2] <- "Fish Tales" 
events[boat3] <- "Marlin"
events[b2_3] <- "Fish Tales / Marlin"


I believe you are looking for something like this.

calendR uses geom_tile() and the fill value so it is not able to be split.  Fortunately, @jan-glx shared geom_tile_split() in response to this question split fill in ggplot geom_tile (or heatmap): two colors by third value.
So we can use that function to update the source code for calendR to get two fill values into one tile on the calendar.
Firstly, here's the code for geom_tile_split() from jan-glx's reponse.
library(rlang)
library(ggplot2)

# A diagonally split version of GeomTile
# by [jan-glx](https://github.com/jan-glx), 
# based on ggplot2::GeomTile by the [ggplot2 authors](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/graphs/contributors)

draw_key_split_tile <- function(data, params, size) {
  
  data$width <- data$width %||% params$width %||% 1
  data$height <- data$height %||% params$height %||% 1
  data$frac<- data$frac %||% params$frac %||% 0.5
  data$width[is.na(data$width)] <- 1
  data$height[is.na(data$height)] <- 1
  data$frac[is.na(data$frac)] <- 0.5
  if (isTRUE(data$split)) {
    x <- c(0, 1, 0)
    y <- c(0, 1, 1)
  } else {
    x <- c(0, 1, 1)
    y <- c(0, 1, 0)
  }
  x <- 0.5 + (x-0.5) * data$width
  y <- 0.5 + (y-0.5) * data$height
  
  grid::polygonGrob(
    x = x,
    y = y,
    default.units = "npc",
    gp = grid::gpar(
      col = data$colour,
      fill = alpha(data$fill, data$alpha)
    )
  )
}


geom_split_tile <- function(mapping = NULL, data = NULL,
                            stat = "identity", position = "identity",
                            ...,
                            linejoin = "mitre",
                            na.rm = FALSE,
                            show.legend = NA,
                            inherit.aes = TRUE) {
  layer(
    data = data,
    mapping = mapping,
    stat = stat,
    geom = GeomSplitTile,
    position = position,
    show.legend = show.legend,
    inherit.aes = inherit.aes,
    params = rlang:::list2(
      linejoin = linejoin,
      na.rm = na.rm,
      ...
    )
  )
}

GeomSplitTile <- ggproto(
  "GeomSplitTile", GeomPolygon,
  extra_params = c("na.rm"),
  
  setup_data = function(data, params) {
    data$width <- data$width %||% params$width %||% resolution(data$x, FALSE)
    data$height <- data$height %||% params$height %||% resolution(data$y, FALSE)
    data$frac<- data$frac %||% params$frac %||% 0.5
    data$split <- as.factor(data$split %||% params$split %||% FALSE)
    
    K = 5
    n <- nrow(data)
    z <- pmin(data$frac, 0.5)*2
    zz <- pmin(1-data$frac, 0.5)*2
    
    new_data <- data.frame(
      x = rep(data$x, each=K) + rep(3-as.integer(data$split)*2, each=K) * as.vector(rbind(-1,  1, 1, zz, -z)) * rep(data$width / 2, each=K),
      y = rep(data$y, each=K) + rep(3-as.integer(data$split)*2, each=K) * as.vector(rbind(-1, -1, 1, z, -zz)) * rep(data$height / 2, each=K),
      group = rep(seq_len(n), each=K)
    )
    new_data <- cbind(new_data, data[rep(seq_len(n), each = K), setdiff(colnames(data), c("x", "y", "group")), drop = FALSE])
    new_data
  },
  
  default_aes = aes(fill = "grey20", colour = NA, linewidth = 0.1, linetype = 1,
                    alpha = NA, width = NA, height = NA, frac =0.5),
  
  required_aes = c("x", "y", "split"),
  
  draw_key = draw_key_split_tile
)

Now here is a minimum viable adaptation from calendR that captures just the functionality you were using in your example, and also removes all of the wonderful guardrails the author built into the function. From here you should be able to see the core of what is driving this output. Though I stripped out the conditional logic to simplify it for your use case, I only made changes to the code as necessary to work with a different input data structure.  This way if you need to add things back in, hopefully you will recognize the code if you go back and look at the source code yourself.
We will call the new function calendR_split.
calendR_split <- function (year = format(Sys.Date(), "%Y"), month = NULL, from = NULL, 
          to = NULL, start = c("S", "M"), orientation = c("portrait", 
                                                          "landscape"), title, title.size = 20, title.col = "gray30", 
          subtitle = "", subtitle.size = 10, subtitle.col = "gray30", 
          text = NULL, text.pos = NULL, text.size = 4, text.col = "gray30", 
          special.days = NULL, special.col = "gray90", gradient = FALSE, 
          low.col = "white", col = "gray30", lwd = 0.5, lty = 1, font.family = "sans", 
          font.style = "plain", day.size = 3, days.col = "gray30", 
          weeknames, weeknames.col = "gray30", weeknames.size = 4.5, 
          week.number = FALSE, week.number.col = "gray30", week.number.size = 8, 
          monthnames, months.size = 10, months.col = "gray30", months.pos = 0.5, 
          mbg.col = "white", legend.pos = "none", legend.title = "", 
          bg.col = "white", bg.img = "", margin = 1, ncol, lunar = FALSE, 
          lunar.col = "gray60", lunar.size = 7, pdf = FALSE, doc_name = "", 
          papersize = "A4") 
{


  ncol <- ifelse(orientation == "landscape" | orientation == 
                     "l", 4, 3)

  months <- format(seq(as.Date("2016-01-01"), as.Date("2016-12-01"), 
                       by = "1 month"), "%B")

  mindate <- as.Date(format(as.Date(paste0(year, "-0", 
                                               1, "-01")), "%Y-%m-01"))
  maxdate <- as.Date(format(as.Date(paste0(year, "-12-", 
                                               31)), "%Y-%m-31"))
  weeknames <- substring(weeknames, 1, 3)

  filler <- dplyr::tibble(date = seq(mindate, maxdate, 
                                       by = "1 day"))
  dates <- seq(mindate, maxdate, by = "1 day")
    
  dates2 <- c(dates, dates) 

  wend <- FALSE

  weekdays <- weeknames
  
  df <- data.frame(week = weekdays, pos.x = 0:6, pos.y = rep(max(t2a$monthweek) + 
                                                               1.75, 7))
  title <- year
  
  week.number.col <- "transparent"
  
  
  


  t1 <- dplyr::tibble(date = dates2, fill = special.days$event) %>% 
                        right_join(filler, by = "date") %>% mutate(dow = ifelse(as.numeric(format(date, "%w")) == 0, 6, as.numeric(format(date, "%w")) - 1)) %>% 
                        mutate(month = format(date, "%B")) %>% 
                        mutate(woy = as.numeric(format(date, "%W"))) %>% 
                        mutate(year = as.numeric(format(date, "%Y"))) %>% 
                        mutate(month = toupper(factor(month, levels = months, ordered = TRUE))) %>% 
                        mutate(monlabel = month) %>%
                        mutate(shift = factor(c(rep(0,length(dates)), rep(1,length(dates)))))
                        
  t2 <- t1 %>% 
      mutate(monlabel = factor(monlabel, ordered = TRUE)) %>% 
      mutate(monlabel = fct_inorder(monlabel)) %>% 
      mutate(monthweek = woy - min(woy), y = max(monthweek) - monthweek + 1) %>% 
      mutate(weekend = ifelse(dow == 6 | dow == 5, 1, 0)) 
    
 
 

  

  p1 <- ggplot(t2, aes(x = dow, y = woy + 1, split = shift, frac = 0.5)) + 
          geom_split_tile(aes(fill = fill), color = col, size = 0, linetype = lty) +
          scale_fill_manual(values = special.col, 
                                 labels = levels(as.factor(special.days$event)), na.value = "white", 
                                 na.translate = FALSE) +
          facet_wrap(~monlabel, ncol = ncol, scales = "free") + 
          ggtitle(title) + labs(subtitle = subtitle) + scale_x_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 
                                                                                 0.01), position = "top", breaks = seq(0, 6), labels = weekdays) + 
          scale_y_continuous(expand = c(0.01, 0.01), trans = "reverse", 
                         breaks = unique(t2$woy) + 1, labels = weeklabels) + 
           geom_text(data = t2a, aes(label = gsub("^0+", "", 
                                            format(date, "%d"))), size = day.size, family = font.family, 
                color = days.col, fontface = font.style) + labs(fill = legend.title) + 
           theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = NA, 
                                            color = NA), strip.background = element_rect(fill = mbg.col, 
                                                                                         color = mbg.col), plot.background = element_rect(fill = bg.col), 
            panel.grid = element_line(colour = ifelse(bg.img == 
                                                        "", bg.col, "transparent")), strip.text.x = element_text(hjust = months.pos, 
                                                                                                                 face = font.style, color = months.col, size = months.size), 
            legend.title = element_text(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
            axis.title = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_text(colour = week.number.col, 
                                    size = week.number.size), axis.text.x = element_text(colour = weeknames.col, 
                                    size = weeknames.size * 2.25), plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5, 
                                    size = title.size, colour = title.col), plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5, 
                                    face = "italic", colour = subtitle.col, size = subtitle.size), 
            legend.position = legend.pos, plot.margin = unit(c(1 * 
                                                                 margin, 0.5 * margin, 1 * margin, 0.5 * margin), 
                                                             "cm"), text = element_text(family = font.family, 
                                                                                        face = font.style), strip.placement = "outsite")


  return(p1)  

}


The way this works is that it takes two values for each date. The first value feeds the upper triangle and the second value feeds the lower triangle. I assumed you would prefer to see a filled box in the case there is only one value, so in the dataset I used here, I populated the same for both values and removed the lines so you don't see a split box.
The input data looks like this. You will note the data is stacked and has twice as many rows as it did in your original.
head(eventsall)

      event shift
1    Holiday     0
2 Fish Tales     0
3  Big Catch     0
4       <NA>     0
5       <NA>     0
6       <NA>     0


I use shift values 0 and 1 to control the split. This is how I made the dataset from the data you provided. When you make your dataframe, call it what you will, but make sure to use the column name "event".
events[c(3, 22, 45, 63, 100, 140, 195, 234, 300)] <- "Big Catch" ## boat 1
events[c(2, 36, 59, 123, 167, 210, 289, 340)] <- "Fish Tales" ## boat 2
events[c(25, 80, 155, 255, 297, 339)] <- "Marlin" ## boat 3
events[c(1, 89, 92, 142, 143, 239, 360, 361)] <- "Holiday" ## holidays

events1[c(3, 22, 45, 63, 100, 140, 195, 234, 300)] <- "Big Catch" ## boat 1
events1[c(36, 59, 123, 167, 210, 289, 340)] <- "Fish Tales" ## boat 2
events1[c(2, 25, 80, 155, 255, 297, 339)] <- "Marlin" ## boat 3
events1[c(1, 89, 92, 142, 143, 239, 360, 361)] <- "Holiday" ## holidays


eventsall <- rbind(data.frame(event = events, shift = 0), data.frame(event = events1, shift = 1))


Finally, this is how you will want to run the function.

calendR_split(year = 2024, start = "M",
        special.days = eventsall,
        special.col = c(ordered_colours), 
        lty = 1, bg.col = "white",    
        subtitle.col = 1,
        weeknames = c("M", "T", "W", "T", "F", "S", "S"),
        day.size = 3.5,
        orientation = "l",
        legend.pos = "bottom"
) 

If you find this an acceptable response, please do visit jan-glx's response and give an up-vote.
